# jQuery multi select questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have to build JS multi select questionnaire.
For grabbing the next question, and increment so we get a new one next time I use the following code:

```
var random = questions[questionIndex++ % questions.length];

        $('#question').text(random.question);

        $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');

        setRadioLabel('radio1', random.options[0]);
        setRadioLabel('radio2', random.options[1]);
        setRadioLabel('radio3', random.options[2]);
        currentQuestion = random;
```

I'm getting an error in line `$('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');`

The error-Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

- I sa

Comment: what is checkboxradio()?

Comment: refresh()Returns: jQuery (plugin only)

update the checkboxradio.
If you manipulate a checkboxradio via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling.

This method does not accept any arguments.
Code examples:
Invoke the refresh method:

1
$( ".selector" ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );